# copyToRealmOrUpdate removed updated object in RealmResults

Tags: android, realm

I just learned about realm and something strange occurred to me. I have 3 activities lets call it A, B, and C.

In activity A (Home Screen) I call a service to download data from internet and stored it in realm.

In activity B (View Screen) I display all of the data using RealmResult and recyclerview

```
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(dataList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
RealmResults<Data> manyData = realm.where(Data.class)
            .equalTo("date", currentDate)
            .findAll();

for (int i = 0; i < manyData.size(); i++) {
    dataList.add(new Data(manyData.get(i).getName(),manyData.get(i).getAge()));
}
rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In activity C (Insert/Update Screen) I try to insert or update the data

Well at first from Activity A and B there is nothing wrong. The recyclerview display the data as I expected. Then something strange happened after I update an object in Activity C.

using

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setId(id);
data.setName(name);
data.setAge(age);
data.setDate(today);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(data);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
finish();
```

after finish(); activity C is cleared from the stack and activity B displayed. But the data which I have updated were removed from the recyclerview which is weird. When I print the manyData.size() in Activity B it shown that the size is smaller by 1 element. Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the problem might be the following:

- When you query the `manyData` in `B` you filter by `date`.
- However when you update the `Data`-object in `C`, the `date` field is
  not set. This results in the `date` field being updated to `null`.
- When you go back to `B` and filter for `currentDate`, the updated
  `Data`-object will not be found since its `date` field is `null`.

As far as I know you cannot not just update certain fields and leave the rest unchanged. Every field will be updated, including those which are `null` (since that could be the desired value which you want to update).

I think the only way to achieve this is by updating from Json, where you can specifically leave certain fields out instead of setting them to `null`.

Comment: It turns out, I accidentally input age as date and date as age. thx for you guidance